# Java restufl service returns Date as String on Glassfish 5. I need number in Milli sec. It works fine on glassfish 4

Tags: java, glassfish, jackson-databind

I have various restful services, which returns various date properties. 
While using glassfish 4 I always get date in number format .e.g

```
  "createdAt": 1549535330000,
```

But when I deploy the application on Glassfish 5 I get the String:

```
 "createdAt": "2019-02-07T10:28:50Z[UTC]",
```

I am using Angular widgets which requires date to be in number format.

I am using Java EE only with no additional framework. For Json binding I am using Jackson:

```
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
```

I would appreciate if some one can help me to deal with this.

> Edited

Please note, I am not using any ZonedDateTime in my code. All the conversion from Entity to json is Automagic.
Please see sample of Entity which contains date:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATED_AT", nullable = false)
protected Date createdAt;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "UPDATED_AT", nullable = false)
protected Date updatedAt;
```

And sample code to fetch the Data with restful service

```
    @Stateless
    @Path("/area")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class AreaResources extends ResourceBase {

@Inject AreaService areaService;


@GET
public List<Area> getAllAreas()
{
List<Area> list= this.areaService.getAllAreasByQuery();
return list;
}
```

How can I make the default return type of Date to be in milliseconds.

Comment: `"2019-02-07T10:28:50Z[UTC]"` would indicate that you're using `ZonedDateTime` in the Java code. That is of course a **guess**, since you didn't show relevant code. You seem to have upgraded to version that now includes support for Java Time API by default, i.e. installs a JavaTimeModule. Since you want different serialization than the default, install your own serializers. If you search the web, you'll find lots of examples for write your own.

Comment: Edited the question with sample and clarification.. may be you can help me a bit more